# in Julia 1.0 what happens to sum when the dims goes to the twilight zone?

Tags: julia

```
julia> [1 2; 3 4]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4

julia> sum([1 2; 3 4]) 
10  

julia> sum([1 2; 3 4],dims=1)
1×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 4  6

julia> sum([1 2; 3 4],dims=2)
2×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 3   
 7
```

Now when I set the argument dims to a tuple, what happens? The official documentation for julia 1.0 does not give me a clue.

```
julia> sum([1 2; 3 4],dims=(1,1))
1×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 4  6

julia> sum([1 2; 3 4],dims=(1,2))
1×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 10  

julia> sum([1 2; 3 4],dims=(2,1))
1×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 10  

julia> sum([1 2; 3 4],dims=(2,2))
2×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 3
 7

julia> sum([1 2; 3 4],dims=(3,4))
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4
```

Looks like it is doing something with the tuples

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `dims` informs which dimensions should be reduced. Additionally:

1. Julia ignores positive indices greater than the number of dimensions of the array
2. duplicates have no effect;
3. ordering of arguments has no effect;
4. only positive arguments are accepted.

So:

- `(1,1)` is the same as `1`;
- `(2,1)` is the same as `(1,2`);
- `(3,4)` is the same as passing no `dims` argument;
- `(1,3,4)` is the same as `1`.
- `0` is an error.

The mechanism is implemented in function `reduced_indices` in Base (it is not exported, but you can look up the implementation).

Comment: Also note that these rules make sense. For example, if you write `sum([1 2; 3 4],dims=(2,2))`, the result is the same as `sum(sum([1 2; 3 4],dims=2), dims=2)`.